# Swap Component Datasources Without Placeholders (Sitecore)

Tags: razor, sitecore, sitecore7

If I bind a component statically, I can't swap out the datasource from the page editor:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("/*Path to rendering*/",
      new { DataSource = "/*Path to datasource*/" })
```

Using a placeholder lets me swap datasources, but requires more overhead and can let the content editor insert multiple components where there should only be one:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("placeholderName")
```

Is there a middle-ground here? I want the content editor to be able to change datasources without having to use a placeholder.

Comment: Just use placeholders, more flexible, caching and more useful for multivar test and personalization. What overhead problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @JanBluemink It just seems like overkill to use them. By overhead I just mean it takes time to create `placeholder settings` and add them where needed. I know it doesn't take much time, but doing it many times eventually adds up. We decided to go with your answer, however, and will continue using placeholders. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Make your datasource path/Guid a field on your current page item?
- Use a placeholder with a very restrictive placeholder setting?

The latter won't stop multiple components but at least it could limit options.

Answer (score 0):

You can personalize your content base on a custom condition ( rule ) where you add a specific condition to sitecore that the content editor can then select the required widget and click personalize then add this custom condition and datasource the widget based if the condition true or false ; This can be used more than one time on the same widget.

for more details check the following:

https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/09/10/custom-rules-and-conditions-for-sitecore-personalization/